# Twine Harlowe: Can I create passage links with the gui? Or any alternative way?

Tags: twine, harlowe

I'm confused how I am expected to organize and write a story within Twine using just the tools outlined in the manual. The main concern revolves around initiating links between my squares/charts/whatever (the passage link system). Am I expected to always manually type [[]] with the correct name of the passage to assign any flow of passage?

I see this as being problematic when designing a story, as you would need to consistently re-position/delete/add-new squares to tell the story properly. I am confused why the gui doesn't seem to support the drop and drag between existing flow arrows? OR does it..? Going in and manually changing the names of everything each time I have to change a position...and needing to use a brand new name cause the existing name won't overwrite or swap. Some people seem to recommend ordering the passage titles by number, but this creates the very problem I am outlining where when changing the position of 3 and 4 you'd have to use like some offbrand title, and do about 8 steps just to swap positions.

Am I supposed to use a different program instead when concocting my story and only use twine once I know where everything goes? Doesn't that defeat the point of it to begin with?

Comment: AFAIK Twine doesn't support GUI based passage linking, the standard harlowe linking technique is the [[link text | passage name]] format. As you mentioned, an alternative workflow could be working in a flowchart/diagram editor to lay things out then implementing in Twine after. Perhaps check out draw.io, it has a free web editor and the GUI drag and drop arrow flow you are looking for. I personally haven't had problems in Twine with rearranging passages but my stories tend to be slightly more linear, I can see how it could be tedious in a more interwoven narrative.

Comment: @disc_code22 that looks to me like it could be an upvote-worthy answer.

Answer (score 2):

Twine does not support GUI based passage linking, you can find a list of story map GUI actions [here, on the Twine Docs](https://twinery.org/wiki/twine2:the_story_map).

The standard Harlowe linking technique is the `[[link text | passage name]]` format, as stated [here in the Harlowe docs](https://twine2.neocities.org/#markup_link), as well as in the general Twine docs, [here](https://twinery.org/wiki/twine2:how_to_create_links).

If you are looking to iterate rapidly on changing passage linkages from a big picture view like the story map, I would consider using a flowchart/diagramming software like [draw.io](http://draw.io) to create a diagram representing the desired story shape and implementing it in Twine.